# Solving a system of modular equatios

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic

Edit: I can't actually see how Chinese remainder theorem works here, if we had only $x$ on the left of each equation I can see how I could work it, but we don't. I can't seem to reduce it down to just $x$ either.

Note: this is a textbook problem.

Describe all integers that satisfy the four following equations. I imagine there will only be one, a I think I can attack this problem using a method I read about on Wikipedia called the chinese remainder theorem, is this a good place to start, or is there a trivial method for solving this?

$$\begin{align*}
\\3{}x + 4 ≡ {}5 \pmod {7}.
\\4x {}+ 5 ≡ 6 \pmod {9}.
\\6x + {}1 ≡{} 7 \pmod {11}.\\7x + 2{} ≡ 8 \pmod {1{}3}.
\end{align*}$$

I will edit in my attempt of the chinese remainder theorem after I get confirmation that it is optimal(if it is), thank you all!

Comment: I suppose CRT would be the best way to solve this, since $7,9,11,13$ are all pairwise coprime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT: For $3x+4\equiv5\mod7$, note that we can first bring the $4$ over to the RHS to get $$3x\equiv1\mod 7.$$
Now, we would like to "divide" the equation by $3$ to rid us of the pesky $3$ on the LHS. To do so, we need to find an inverse for $3$ modulo $7$. To do so, we would need to turn to the Euclidean algorithm with $3$ and $7$ because it would give us $u$ and $v$ such that $$3u+7v=1\implies 3u=1\mod7.$$

Think you can take it from here? (Mouse over to see what $3x\equiv1\mod 7$ becomes.)

> $3x\equiv1\mod 7$ becomes $x\equiv 5 \mod 7$ because $5$ is the inverse of $3$ modulo $7$.

I'll leave the CRT bit (which is the fun bit) to you. :)

Comment: What about the last two, which become 6 mod 11 and 6 mod 13?

I can't just find the inverse in this case

Comment: @Katie Have you used Euclid's algorithm? May I see what you have for $13$? I'll show you $11$: $2\times6-11=1$.

Comment: I meant that the last two lines become $6x \equiv 6 \pmod {11}$ and $7x \equiv 6 \pmod {13}$, and now I can't just work out the inverse to find it

Comment: Nevermind I got it, thank you for your help!

Comment: @Katie Sorry I was away, but glad you got it!